# Do I have time to visit downtown London during a 4-hour layover at Heathrow?

Tags: uk, london

I'm a US citizen. I have a 4-hour layover in London. I don't have heavy luggage, just a backpack. What are the most time-optimal choices for transport to get downtown, have a meal, take a picture, then get back to the airport?

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to calculate with being back at the airport _at least_ an hour before your scheduled departure, to have time for security lines and getting to your gate. And get the backpack checked through so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: The more I think about this the more risky it sounds.  Is 4 hours simply not enough to do the minimum?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't risk it; a routine screwup-of-the-day on the railway can make you miss your connecting flight.

Comment: Yeah thought so.  Well thats that then.  Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You could try taking a taxi to Windsor and back take a photo of the castle there. It's about 20 minutes away from Heathrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optimal in terms of time or money?

London has 5 airports, but a US citizen will probably transit through Heathrow.

There are three reasonable options to go to central London.

- Taxi. Expensive but only fast if there are no traffic problems.
- Heathrow express. Fast and expensive, to Paddington railway station,
  but unless you want to visit Madame Tussaud's waxworks museum you'll
  need to travel on.
- Underground. Is the cheapest option. The Piccadilly line will take you
  to central London in less than an hour, but is boring. Not subject to overland
  traffic problems, it is easy to use, and with little luggage; that is
  my optimal choice.

Comment: So leave at least 2 hours for transport i'm guessing? immigration is another hour ? So around 60 minutes for anything else?

Comment: @MisterOH: Heathrow Express is considerably faster, 15 minutes running time and departs every 15 minutes. But depending on where you want to go, you'll need some onward transport from Paddington.

Comment: Subject to the frequency of trains. The timetables can be looked up.

Comment: The tube could be held up by the man that decides today is the day to end it all by jumping on the tracks at Acton Town or a similar event.

Comment: @Sarriesfan if you plan your life around terrorism, they have achieved their objective.

Comment: Clearing UK customs and immigration, getting Tube tickets, then spending about 100 minutes round trip on the train to central London (maybe a little less; it took us 45 minutes to get to Kensington station)... needing an hour as a buffer when returning, for security... that might leave 45 minutes or so of visiting London.  Seems risky for such a short visit.

Comment: @WeatherVane How is terrorism involved? I think the point here is just that trains can have delays for a wide variety of reasons (including people who intentionally go onto the tracks) and that cutting it close means a higher risk of missing your flight.

Comment: Weathervane since when is suicide terrorism ? People living in and around London know the euphemism "A person on the track" all too well. There are also,many other types of incident that can mean that trains are late delayed or cancelled. For instance Yesterday was gay pride day in Brighton for example and the queues getting onto some train stations such as Blackfriars caused problems throughout the TFL network as some stations were  closed for short periods to allow crowds to thin for safety reasons.

Comment: @Sarriesfan mybad but still, there is no foolproof way to catch the next flight, perhaps not even by staying in the transit lounge.

Comment: No but the chance of missing the fight increase the further away from the airport you go, if you are in transit lounge something has to go seriously wrong to miss it.

Comment: @Sarriesfan like, you fall asleep. That is not a rare occurrence.

Answer (score 17):

4 hours from Heathrow really isn't going to give you sufficient time:

- Immigration. Their official service standard for non-EU citizens is 95% of passengers getting through in 45 minutes or less. [They don't achieve that standard.](https://www.heathrow.com/file_source/Company/Static/PDF/Companynewsandinformation/Border_Force_Performance_Jun18.pdf) It's hard to predict, as you don't know how many flights are arriving at the same time as yours, but this could take an hour or more.
- To/from London. By [Heathrow Express](https://www.heathrowexpress.com/), which is fast but expensive, it's a 15 minute trip and runs every 15 minutes. So that's a half hour of train time, plus 0 (best case) - 15 (average case) - 30 (worst case) minutes of waiting time, plus time walking to/from platforms.
- Back to Heathrow. It's a large unfamiliar airport, and you'll need to go through security and get to your gate sufficiently before boarding closes, or you'll miss your flight. Let's say you aim to get back 1.5 hours before your departure time.

You'd be left with 30-45 minutes of actual free time, and you'd be starting at Paddington Station, which doesn't give you much for an iconic photo.

And any complication (a delayed flight, a longer wait at immigration or security, a small train delay, etc...) would be enough to mess this up.

I personally enjoy madcap adventures doing layovers, and I'd skip this one. You could buy access to [a lounge](https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/londonheathrow.htm#lounge) in your terminal if you want a more comfortable place to wait.